# Reading values in dynamic drop down menus using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic

I am using a Javascript function so that the user can create some html controls on the fly, such as whenever he needs to add a text field he can call this function, the function can be used to create these dynamic controls including text fields, drop down menus and radio buttons which I treat them in the code as arrays

After the user creates this controls on the fly; he uses them to enter values and I am writing a php code to read the arrays values in order to inset them later into the MySQL DB but the php code I am using can only read the value of the first drop down in an array and can't read the rest of the values although the same code is working fine with text fields and radio buttons:

HYG the HTML code that is inserted for the text fields drop down menus whenever the user calls the JS function:

```
<input type="text" name="APersonName[]" value="" placeholder="Full Name" />

<select name="APersonRelation[]" size="1">
<option selected=selected value="Relationship">Relationship</option>
<option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
<option value="Friend">Friend</option>
<option value="Parent">Parent</option>
<option value="Child">Child</option>
</select>
```

And HYG the PHP code that I am using to read the text fields and the drop down (select input type)

For text fields it works:

```
$name = implode(",", $_POST["APersonName"]);
echo $name . "<P>";
```

For drop downs it doesn't work:

```
$relation = implode(",", $_POST["APersonRelation"]);
echo $relation . "<P>";
```

Am I missing something regarding the drop down menus should the value of the drop down referenced in some other way while I am handling it as an array?

Adding the JS function that creates the dynamic controls:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount < 5) {
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            var clonedChildren = newcell.children;
            var childTable = newcell.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0];
            for (var i = 0; i < childTable.rows.length; i++) {
                var colCnt = childTable.rows[i].cells.length;
                for (var j = 0; j < colCnt; j++) {
                    var children = childTable.rows[i].cells[j].children;
                    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
                        if (children[k].tagName == 'SELECT') {
                            children[k].name = "Row" + rowCount + children[k].name;
                        } else if (children[k].tagName == 'INPUT') {
                            if (children[k].type == "radio") {
                                children[k].name = "Gala[" + rowCount + "]";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please submit the form.");
    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be expecting only one value instead of an array ? I don't think you want to retrieve all the options :) --- Can't be `Child` and `Spouse` at the same time :)

Comment: The JS function creates more than one text field and more than one drop down so each drop down has the same values which corresponds to different text fields (names) so for example the user will create two text fields (name) and two drop downs (relationship), will enter his name in the first text field and chooses husband and then enters his wife name in the second text field and chooses from the corresponding drop down wife and then submits the form which will call the php code to enter these values in the DB

Comment: So you can imagine it as an array of the same control which works fine with text fields but doesn't work with drop downs which I think is related somehow to the fact that the drop down itself contains an array of values, perhaps I need to use some sort of a multidimensional array or something, don't know !